# TypeError 'set' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, typeerror

I need to know why it won't let me increase the value of the assignment by 1:

```
keywords = {'states' : 0, 'observations' : 1, 'transition_probability' : 2, 'emission_probability' : 3}
keylines = {-1,-1,-1,-1}

lines = file.readlines()
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    line = lines[i].rstrip()
    if line in keywords.keys():
        keylines[keywords[line]] = i + 1 << this is where it is giving me the error
```

I ran it as a class and it worked fine, but now as an in-line code piece it gives me this error.

Comment: Try `keylines = [-1,-1,-1,-1]`; a set could only hold one `-1` anyway. *"I ran it as a class and it worked fine"* - no, you are mistaken.

Comment: Correction: "I ran it in a class and it worked fine."

Comment: No, it didn't. It can't have. Being in a class doesn't make that a legal thing to do to a set!

Comment: Say what you will, but this is the EXACT same code I used from my class. You can be butthurt that it works in my class and not in this struct all you want, but it doesn't change the fact that it works.

Comment: Set objects, as the error message tells you, *don't support item assignment*. They don't support it in a function, they don't support it in a module and they don't support it in a class. That's just a fact. You don't actually show the example where you thought it was working, but either the line with the error was different or the line defining `keylines` was different, as a comparison of the two would have told you without needing to ask the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a set, you want a list, which is created with square brackets:

```
keylines = [-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised at the lack of answers here, so adding one that hits on one of the more common ways this manifests here in case anyone else hits this from Search and needs to know.

It's unclear if the OP is trying to use it as a set or a second dictionary, but in my case I encountered the error due to a common pitfall in Python.

It hinges on two things:

In Python, Dictionaries and sets both use { }. (as of python 3.10.2)

You cannot create a dictionary with only keys and no values.  Due to this, if you just do a_dict = {1, 2, 3} you don't make a dict, you make a set, as shown in this example:

```
In [1]: test_dict = {1, 2, 3}
   ...: test_set = {1, 2, 3}
   ...:
   ...: print(f"{type(test_dict)=} {type(test_set)=}")

type(test_dict)=<class 'set'> 
type(test_set)=<class 'set'>
```

If you want to declare a dictionary with just it's keys, you'll add values to your key:value pairs.  However, [you can use None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079681/initializing-a-dictionary-in-python-with-a-key-value-and-no-corresponding-values#comment29913632_20079681):

```
In [4]: test_dict = {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
   ...: test_set = {1, 2, 3}
   ...:
   ...: print(f"{type(test_dict)=} {type(test_set)=}")
type(test_dict)=<class 'dict'> 
type(test_set)=<class 'set'>
```

or [dict.fromkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079807/17960696)([1, 2, 3])