# Can I access a classes constructor variables the someway as in JS?

Tags: java, class

Is it possible to access the variables of a object the same way you can in JS.

For example:

```
import java.util.*;
class Dice{
    public String [] side;
    public String name;

    public Dice (String n, String ... a){
        name = n;
        side = a;

    }

    //Setter and Getter side
    public String getSide(){
        return side;
    }
    public void setSide(String s){
        side = n;
    }

}
```

The array is initialized in main like so:

`Dice easy = new Dice("Green:","Brain","Brain","Brain","Foot Print","Foot Print","Shotgun");`

It has a name "Green".

The rest of the objects Strings are stored inside a String array.

To access the array in JS you can:

`Dice.side[1];`

Can we access them in Java like this, I am trying to access the array in main()?

`String theStringInArray = Dice.side[1];`

`System.out.println(theStringInArray);`

The result should print "Brain" in this example.

(This is only for myself and to gain practice I have been reading about ArrayLists but only using arrays in this example :)

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: `side` is an *instance* variable - each instance will have a separate variable. In this case, you just need `easy.side[1]` rather than `Dice.side[1]`... although I would advise against public fields in general.

Comment: @ Scott Hunte, What about this gut Scott???? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079681/initializing-a-dictionary-in-python-with-a-key-value-and-no-corresponding-values/20079718#20079718

Comment: @ Jon Skeet, Thanks for the help I got the problem now it was this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dice easy = new Dice("Green:","Brain","Brain","Brain","Foot Print","Foot Print","Shotgun");

String theStringInArray = easy.side[1]; // getting the value through instance (easy)

System.out.println(theStringInArray);
```

If you really want to access like `Dice.side[1]`; you have to make `side` array a static variable.

```
public static String [] side;
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me the other day too : )